# Fancybox jQuery media helper - player stuck on loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

So, I'm kinda new to jquery, and this is the first time I've had to deal with the issue I'm having at the moment.

I think it's an interference with Wordpress suddenly updating to 3.9 - 3.9.1 or something, though I can't specifically nail it down.

So the way this site works is that I had the boxes with the videos work like they do now, you clicked play and it would pop up in a fancybox and start playing the video.

It still does this - however, it will just show the loader, and not actually load the fancybox.

And before you ask, I could only get it working in the first place with jquery 1.11, due to various conflicts, but now it suddenly wont work at all.

http://ramborg.com/commercial <- You can see the issue here.

The videos shown are mostly Vimeo, I'm pretty sure they all are, but maybe there has been some YT also added, but that wouldn't matter, if the media helper actually worked.

Any ideas, and input would be greatly appreciated, before I just revert down to an older version of WP to make it work again.

EDIT: Appearntly the fancybox will EVENTUALLY load, it's just heavily delayed. It took like 1-2 minutes into a video before it loaded. If you goto Stills the fancybox will load almost right away (it's just an image). It's almost like it wont open the fancybox until the video is done buffering?

EDIT2: From what I can garner from console/inspect in Chrome, is that it's struggling with loading player.js from Vimeo? Is that the error the rest of you see aswell? Any way I could solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked. The videos all load promptly, and no errors in the console in chrome. Try loading the page both while logged in to wordpress and logged out to see if there is a difference.

Comment: It seems Vimeo it self had problem with player.js yesterday. No worries. Thanks though either way, I'll put it to answered as it's now working as intended.